# Geometric series of a $V_{2} = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty } \beta ^{t} \frac{\left ( \gamma^{t} \right )^{1-\rho}}{1-\rho}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

What is the geometric series of this $$V_{2} = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty } \beta ^{t} \frac{\left ( \gamma^{t}  \right )^{1-\rho}}{1-\rho}?$$

I am getting this answer: $$V_{2} = \frac{1}{1-\rho} \sum_{t=0}^{\infty }\beta^{t} \left ( \gamma^{t}  \right )^{1-\rho}$$
$$V_{2} = \frac{1}{1 - \rho}\left ( 1 + \beta \gamma^{1 - \rho} + \beta ^{2} \gamma ^{2(1-\rho)} + ...  \right )$$
$$V_{2} = \frac{1}{1 - \rho} \frac{1}{1 - \beta \gamma^{1 - \rho} }.$$

However, in the solution the answer is $$V_{2t} = \frac{\gamma ^{t}}{1 - \beta \gamma^{1 - \rho} }.$$

Can anyone explain to me how the answer has a numerator of $\gamma^{t}$? Forget about the $1-\rho$ term which the answer clearly disregards.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong with either the answer or the question. $t$ is a dummy index in the summation and can't possibly appear in the closed form.

Comment: $t$ is the time component $t \in \left [0, \infty  \right )$

Comment: You're correct, the reference is not.

Comment: @Dr.MV Cool. Thanks!